# How to Find Key in Groovy

Tags: dictionary, groovy

```
public String find(int number) {
    String name = phoneBookMap.get(number);
    if (name!=null) {
        return name;
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

If you have the key and the value

```
name:Jone 
number:1234 
phoneBookMap = [Jone : 1234]
```

What is the way to find a `name` only with `number`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to search by value, something like:

```
String find(int number) {
    phoneBookMap.entrySet().find{it.value == number}?.key ?: -1
}
```